# i get some error in sitemap xml type in laravel

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, xml-error

i have some problem to my xml file type in my site

it`s work correct but at now i get some text in last line of my file

`new (class{constructor(e){this.client=window[Symbol.for(e)],this.bindEvents()}bindEvents(){const e=this;var t;history.pushState=(t=history.pushState,function(){const n=t.apply(this,arguments);return e.onUrlChange(),n});let n=!0;history.replaceState=(t=>function(s){var r=t.apply(this,arguments);return n||e.onUrlChange(),n=!1,r})(history.replaceState),window.addEventListener("hashchange",(function(){e.onUrlChange()}))}onUrlChange(){this.client.emitToBg("URLS_SAFE_CHECK__CONTENT_URL_REWRITED")}})('MARIO_POST_CLIENT_eppiocemhmnlbhjplcgkofciiegomcon')`

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browser extension is adding that code. If you look at the response in network tab you will see that response is correct. I had same issue when I was using urbanVPN extension.

Answer (score 0):

I get same problem when connect css file to xml. Try xsl stylesheet.
My resolution of problem.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output 
              method="html" 
              doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
              doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" 
              indent="yes" />

  <!-- 
    Шаблон корневого элемента
    -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Наши книги</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        * {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px
        }
        
        h1 {
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          background-color: #ccf
        }
        
        table {
          margin: 10px;
          border-collapse: collapse
        }
        
        td {
          border: 1px solid gray;
          padding: 5px
        }
        
        thead td {
          text-align: center;
          background-color: #ccf;
          font-weight: bold
        }
        
        #colTitle {
          width: 300px
        }
        
        #colAutor {
          width: 300px
        }
        
        #colPubYear {
          width: 100px
        }
        
        #colPrice {
          width: 100px
        }
        
        .expenceBook td {
          background-color: yellow
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Наши книги</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <td id="colTitle">Наименование</td>
          <td id="colAutor">Автор</td>
          <td id="colPubYear">Год издания</td>
          <td id="colPrice">Цена</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/book" />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>

    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- 
    Шаблон отрисовки книги стоимостью менее 200 руб.
    -->
  <xsl:template match="book[price &lt; 200]">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- 
    Шаблон отрисовки книги стоимостью более 200 руб.
    -->
  <xsl:template match="book[price &gt; 200]">
    <tr class="expenceBook">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- 
    Шаблон отрисовки дочерних элементов книги
    -->
  <xsl:template match="book/*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```